# GitLab CI pipeline can't find the path for gulp.js

Tags: docker, gulp, pipeline, gitlab-ci

I'm a tad new to this. I've been writing a pipeline that's just for training purposes and I've encountered probably like 15 different errors but the one I'm at currently is really ruining all my fun since I can't get around it.
This is my code:

```
    stages:
  - lint-css
  - lint-js
  - unit-test

image: git.chaosgroup.com:4567/philipa.hristova/test33004__half/dind_node:latest

lint css:
  stage: lint-css
  before_script:
  cache:
    untracked: true
  tags:
    - docker
  only:
    - web
  script:
    - ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js lint-css

lint js:
  stage: lint-js
  cache:
    untracked: true
    policy: pull
  tags:
    - docker
  only:
    - web
  script:
    - ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js lint-js

run unit test:
  stage: unit-test
  cache:
    untracked: true
  tags:
    - docker
  only:
    - web
  script:
    - ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js test
```

And the docker image I am using is one I made over a docker:dind image, adding nodejs, npm and gulp. The error I get is this:
[image]

Comment: Just a quick guess, but aren‘t you missing yarn or npm install?

Comment: I did npm install on the docker container before pushing it to the registry. Maybe that's not the same as writing in the before_script?

Comment: Dude thank you so much adding it worked but can you please explain to me why it's different than doing npm install in the image and then pushing it?

Comment: @Clairvoyant Are you sure you have installed it in the same path that gitlab is trying to execute it?